# Ubuntu system files cannot access Internet

Tags: upgrade, internet, 19.10

I am currently on Ubuntu 19.10, planning on upgrading to 20.04, the problem is none of the GUI Applications can access Internet on this Laptop.
I will be attaching screenshots of my various tries.

[image: on <code>do-release-upgrade</code>]
[image: On Clicking check for updates.]
[image: on <code>do-release-upgrade -d</code>]

Please feel free to change the Title, I cannot come up on how exactly to describe it.
Thank you! :)
As pointed by a user, my current version using  `lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
 Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
 Description:   Ubuntu 19.10
 Release:   19.10
 Codename:  eoan
```

Comment: Your screenshot output shows that you seem to be using 19.04 sources. 19.04 is EOL. Upgrade to 19.10 first, then 20.04 will be available. Looks like you had a botched or incomplete upgrade in the past. Don't ignore such problems - they get worse with time, as you have discovered. Also, 20.04 hasn't been released yet - expect it later today....but not quite yet.

Comment: This is actually weird, since in my about section it also shows 19.10, would you be able to guide me to "complete" the upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be that the `disco`(Ubuntu 19.04) repositories on my `/etc/apt/sources.list`, which now is EOL(End Of Life).
Now to fix this, I will have to either comment or remove the lines in the sources.list file.
This could be done by

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and then find and comment all the files that had the word `Disco` in it.
like:

```
'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates Release'
 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security'
```

which could be either commented out using a `#` sign.

Thank you!